# Unable to mount media hard drivrs. after [user@machine ~]$ sudo usermod -G dialout user

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, password, users

I wasn't able to download date from my USB cradle from a Powertap cycling computer after upgrading to 12.10. I thought I found the answer with a google search that suggested using this code where user is my username. Unfortunately now my media hard drives won't mount. I am the only user of this computer and should have superuser privileges. When I try to mount the hard drives I am asked for a password but my password doesn't work. It also won't let me take a screenshot. Action: org.freedesktop.udisk2.filesystem-mount-system. FWIW the cradle is downloading fine but it looks like the code removed or changed my superuser password

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `-a` switch to add, rather than replace your groups.  Now you are ONLY in the dialout group.  You will need to boot into rescue mode and go to a root shell, make sure the disk is mounted r/w, and put yourself back in the other groups:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
usermod -G dialout,adm,cdrom,plugdev,admin
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried booting into the root shell and used "usermod -a -G admin username" followed by a reboot. Now I can't get Grub to load using the shift key. Is there another way to reboot into grub?